# Enable digraph only for certain characters

Tags: digraphs

I have digraph enabled

```
:set digraph
```

I really like the digraph setting in vim, but I often find it changes my keystrokes to some foreign character without my intention. I can see that there are around 13.000 characters defined, and the chance of hitting a combination, and a backspace in between, is just too high. In the end I will only use around 10 of these characters anyway. So my question is, can I enable digraph only for a set of predefined characters? Or do I need to resort to the CTRL-k option? Or define my own mappings?

Answer (score 3):

If there are literally only ten, then a simple, albeit inelegant, solution would be to leave `'digraph'` switched off and just hard code the desired behaviour with ten insert mode mappings, e.g.:

```
:inoremap e<BS>' é
:inoremap i<BS>: ï
```

It's not a perfect solution, because it results in slightly delayed/odd redraw while you are halfway through typing the mapping, but at the speed most people type in insert mode you might not find it a big issue in practice.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned the mapping solution myself. I tried to avoid it, but there seems to be no way around it. This solution at least has the benefit of defining my own shortcut, e.g. I could replace `<BS>` with `<leader>`.

Comment: @pfnuesel Ugh, sorry. Somehow missed that last sentence.

Comment: For 10 digraphs that might be overkill but what about a snippet manager? You define your 10 snippets to simply insert the character you want to and this way you don't have a delay in insert mode. (But once again a snippet manager just for that isn't necessarily the best solution)